# C# - How To Mathematical Operations In DataTable

Tags: c#, math, datagridview, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable and I want to do some mathematical operations before adding them to DataGridView. First one, I want to find maximum number of third column of my DataTable, second one I want to divide all values in third column with this maximum number. After all I want to replace my new values instead old values. My DataTable looks like that;

```
        Column 1     Column 2     Column 3
     ---------------------------------------
          a             b          2000000
          q             r          250000
          s             t          185000
          m             w          400000
          o             p          750000
```

After the operations, my DataTable should look like that;

```
        Column 1     Column 2     Column 3
     ---------------------------------------
          a             b          1
          q             r          0.125
          s             t          0.0925
          m             w          0.0002
          o             p          0.375
```

It's my code;

```
      connection.Open();
      //Some insignificant operations here.
      for (int q = 0; q < w.Length; q++)
      {
          for (int a = q + 1; a < w.Length; a++)
          {
              string query = ".....";
              SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
              DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
              myAdapter.Fill(myTable);
              //I started here for finding maximum number in DataTable.
              int[] myColumn = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("Column3")).ToArray();
              int myMaximum = myColumn.Max();
              //I don't know what should I do after that.
              foreach (DataRow myRows in myTable.Rows)
              {
                  //Some significant operations again...
                  dgv1.Rows.Add(...);
              }
          }
      }
      connection.Close();
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: I don't know how to apply this mathematical operation for all Column3 in my DataTable and I want to replace my new values instead old values before adding them to DataGridView.

Comment: And are you mostly interesting in how to do this the way you've described, or do you just want help getting the result you're after? For instance you could do the maths you describe in the SQL statement itself if you prefer.

Comment: I need to C# code. I tried it in SQL statement but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
var max = myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Max(r => r.Field<double>("Column 3"));

foreach (var row in myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    row["Column 3"] = row.Field<double>("Column 3") / max;
}
```

---

Runable test code:

```
var myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add("Column 3", typeof(double));
myTable.Rows.Add(20_00_000);
myTable.Rows.Add(250_000);
myTable.Rows.Add(185_000);
myTable.Rows.Add(400_000);
myTable.Rows.Add(750_000);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.Field<double>("Column 3"))));    

var max = myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Max(r => r.Field<double>("Column 3"));

foreach (var row in myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
{
    row["Column 3"] = row.Field<double>("Column 3") / max;
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.Field<double>("Column 3"))));
```

This outputs:

```
2000000, 250000, 185000, 400000, 750000
1, 0.125, 0.0925, 0.2, 0.375
```

---

Update based on "Column 3" being an `int`.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.Field<int>("Column 3"))));

int max = myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Max(r => r.Field<int>("Column 3"));
double[] results = myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => (double)r.Field<int>("Column 3") / max).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", results));
```

Now just index in to `results` when you build your `DataGridView`.

Comment: Should I write this code in my foreach or somewhere else?

Comment: @heyyoucoder - What do you think will happen if you do put it in your `foreach`?

Comment: I asked it because the code you sent didn't change the values.

Comment: @heyyoucoder - It did when I tested it in my environment here.

Comment: It says; "System.InvalidCastException: Specific cast is not valid" for this row; var max = myTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Max(r => r.Field<double>("Column 3"));

Comment: @heyyoucoder - What type is your column defined as?

Comment: It's int in SQL server. But I tried Int32 the code you sent, and it returns 100 for all my values in DataGridView.

Comment: @heyyoucoder - Your question says "After the operations, my DataTable should look like that;" - and it shows `double` values in "Column 3". You need to be precise in your questions.

Comment: @heyyoucoder - I've added an update to deal with the data in Column 3 being an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding a 4th column to the existing table? Make the column an “Expression” column to do the math as you describe, then hide the third column?

An example of this is below…

```
DataTable GridTable;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridTable = GetDataTable();
  FillTable(GridTable);
  AddExpressionColumn(GridTable);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
  dataGridView1.Columns["Column3"].Visible = false;
}

private DataTable GetDataTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(int));
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Rows.Add("a", "b", 2000000);
  dt.Rows.Add("q", "r", 250000);
  dt.Rows.Add("s", "t", 185000);
  dt.Rows.Add("m", "w", 400000);
  dt.Rows.Add("o", "p", 750000);
}

private void AddExpressionColumn(DataTable dt) {
  DataColumn expCol = new DataColumn("Result", typeof(decimal));
  dt.Columns.Add(expCol);
  string expressionString = "Column3 / " + GetMaxValue(dt).ToString();
  expCol.Expression = expressionString;
}

private int GetMaxValue(DataTable dt) {
  int max = (int)dt.Compute("Max(Column3)", "");
  if (max == 0)
    return 1;
  return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest get rid of `DataTable` and work with a plain c# classes.
`DataTable` is "heavy" structure which do much more than you need and in most of the cases you don't need it.

Create class to represent your data

```
public class Item
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public int Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

Load data

```
public List<Item> LoadData()
{
    var query = "SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = query;

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var data = new List<Item>();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                var item = new Item
                {
                    Column1 = reader.GetString(0),
                    Column1 = reader.GetString(1),
                    Column1 = reader.GetInt32(2)
                };
                data.Add(item);
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Create class which will represent calculated data

```
public class CalculatedItem
{
    public string Column1 { get; }
    public string Column2 { get; }
    public decimal Calculated { get; }

    public CalculatedItem(Item item, decimal maxValue)
    {
        Column1 = item.Column1;
        Column2 = item.Column2;
        Calculated = (decimal)item.Column3 / maxValue
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var data = LoadData();
var maxValue = data.Select(item => item.Column3).Max();
var calculatedData = data.Select(item => new CalculatedItem(item, maxValue)).ToList();

// Bind data to the DataGridView
DataGridView1.DataSource = calculatedDate;
```